# How to continue doing something?

Tags: grammar-choice, verbs, syntax

There are many Latin verbs meaning roughly "continue", but I failed to find a description how to use any of them with another verb.
I would like to say things like "Keep walking!" and "She continues to study Greek." and other similar thing having to do with continuing to do something.

Which verb should I use and how?
Should I use infinitive, gerund, participle, or something else?

Comment: From my early search, I imagine Latin uses a single verb rather than a compound one. In a sense, "keep walking!" can be proxied by "_vada_" or _vada iterum_ or _vada itera_. and "she continues to study" by "est studeo" or "est studeo iterum".  I [compiled a list](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9W37V5qqyF/) of Latin/English texts from a Pope Francis' text where the English has a compound verb in the sense you mean, and where I see (beware) no particular form arising. You might get a different idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a somewhat roundabout possibility: ***non desinere* + infinitive.** I think this captures the common emphasis of "continue" in your examples: "despite X, I don't stop...."

- "Keep walking!" = *ne desinas ambulare!*
- "She continues to study Greek." = *Graecis studere litteris non desinit.*